# Problem with implicit conversion and null

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have this function

```
public static implicit operator MyClass(string v) { return new MyClass(v); }
```

and write var.myclass = null;. This calls the implicit operator and passes null as string, which causes havoc in my code (i use reflection and would not like to add a special case). How can i write myclass = null without causing the implicit operator?

I tried writing

```
public static implicit operator MyClass(string v) { return  v == null ? null : new MyClass(v); }
```

But that causes a stackoverflow

Comment: Is MyClass a struct? What argument does your constructor take?

Comment: Can you write it as an explicit operator instead?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue; you probably have something else wrong.

Comment: d'oh, it makes sense. You cant have a null struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that both sides of the ternary operator must be of the same or compatible types.

Try writing

```
if (v == null)
    return null;
else
    return new MyClass(v);
```

**EDIT**: I can only reproduce your issue if I make `MyClass` a struct, in which case your question is impossible; a struct *cannot* be null.

Please provide more details.

Comment: You're thinking of a compile time error, which would be fixed by changing it to:
return v == null ? (MyClass)null : new MyClass(v);

The stack overflow is likely going to be a runtime error, where it calls the implicit operator recursively.

Comment: It's an implicit cast - the compiler would automatically insert the `(MyClass)`

Comment: Big thanks tho :) you got my answer while i provided incorrect details!